# how to find and rename field name in mongodb 3.2

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

how can I rename field name in MongoDB?

I want to replace all the field names that start with $ to &.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some link and make a proper solution for you problem

First you need to get your all column, you could do this with MapReduce:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "my_collection",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
});
```

Then run distinct on the resulting collection so as to find all the keys:

```
columns = db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
```

And rename the all matching columns

```
columns.forEach(function(columnName) {
    if (columnName.indexOf('$') == 0) {
        var newColumnName = columnName.replace('$', '&');
        rename_query = { '$rename': {} };
        rename_query['$rename'][columnName] = newColumnName;
        db.my_collection.updateMany({}, rename_query)
    }
})
```

Reference link are

[MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection)

[MongoDB $rename javascript variable for key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769644/mongodb-rename-javascript-variable-for-key-name)

Comment: Actually, I don't know the field name, all I know is there are fields which start with $.  is there any like operator which we can use?

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your requerment

Comment: Thanks @gaurav, i have another issue few field names are in array.

Comment: below is sample document {
        "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
        "op" : "command",
        "ns" : "test.test",
        "command" : {
                "aggregate" : "test",
                "pipeline" : [
                        {
                                "$match" : {
                                        "identifier" : "U1",
                                        "audience" : /^agent$/i
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "$limit" : 1
                        }
                ],